# how can I get this function template to work reguardless of whether I pass a string literal or a string object?

Tags: c++, templates, stdstring

I have the following function template that takes any type of map and returns either the value associated with a certain key or a default value provided at the call site:

```
template <template <typename Key, typename Val, typename ...Args> typename C, typename Key, typename Val, typename ...Args>
Val get_or_default(C<Key, Val, Args...> const& my_map, Key const& k, Val const& v)
{
    typename C<Key, Val, Args...>::const_iterator const it = my_map.find(k);
    return (it != my_map.end()) ? it->second : v;
}
```

when I call the function this way:

```
// initialize map
    std::map<std::string, int> m1{ {"jim",1},{"mark",2},{"sally",3} };
// call get_or_default with std::string as key arg
    std::cout << get_or_default(m1, std::string("jim"), -1) << std::endl;
```

everything works as expected, however when I call the function like:

```
std::cout << get_or_default(m1, "jim", -1) << std::endl;
```

I get the following error message:

```
error C2782: 'Val get_or_default(const C<Key,Val,Args...> &,const Key &,const Val &)': template parameter 'Key' is ambiguous
```

I think that the parameter `Key` is ambiguous because it is being called with `std::string` in the map template but as `const char*` for the second parameter of `get_or_default`

How can I get this function to work regardless of whether I am passing a string object or a string literal?

Thank you for any help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting conflicting deduction for the `Key` template parameter, you can simply make one of the `Key` arguments a non-deduced context.

First provide a simple type-identity struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct I { using type = T; };
```

and then use it like this:

```
template <template <typename Key, typename Val, typename ...Args> typename C,typename Key, typename Val, typename ...Args>
Val get_or_default(C<Key, Val, Args...> const& my_map, typename I<Key>::type  const &k, Val const& v)
{
    typename C<Key, Val, Args...>::const_iterator const it = my_map.find(k);
    return (it != my_map.end()) ? it->second : v;
}
```

You can simplify this a bit. Remove the template template parameter names, since they are not used anyway. Also, you can use `auto` for the iterator type. Also, the variadic arguments don't seem to be used for any purpose.

```
template <template <typename, typename> typename C, typename Key, typename Val>
Val get_or_default(C<Key, Val> const& my_map, typename I<Key>::type const &k, Val const& v)
{
    auto const it = my_map.find(k);
    return (it != my_map.end()) ? it->second : v;
}
```

Here's a working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/yHBRmN).

Comment: That worked great!  I also added another type-identity struct for the value parameter, since I was having the same problem there.

Comment: That's great. Take a look at @dev65's answer as well though. You might not need this additional complexity at all.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you :

```
template<class C, class Key, class Val>
Val get_or_default(C const& mp, Key const& k, Val const& v)
{
    typename C::const_iterator it = mp.find(k);
    return (it != mp.end()) ? it->second : v;
}
```

If you want better type restrictions and error messages and c++ 20 is an option then concepts are the way to go

Comment: This seems to not work if I pass the string literal in the `val` argument. for some reason, it only converts the string literal to std::string for the maps key.  which is what I asked for in my question, you so you weren't wrong that this works, but the answer from @cigien works for any number of parameters.